# The --model option does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, cmd

If I type the following command in cmd:

```
php artisan make:policy CvPolicy --model=Cv
```

I will get:

> The --model option does not exist

I solve this by typing:

```
php artisan make:policy CvPolicy
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Check if you have ```MODEL Class``` ```Cv ``` in project. I guess command can not find model ```Cv``` in your project

Comment: The model option was added in Laravel 5.3. What version are you using?

Comment: What does `php artisan make:policy --help` show? Does it have a `--model` param?

Comment: have you seen my answer, the problem still exists?

Answer (score 4):

You should try this:

please check below example

```
 php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated policy will be placed in the `app/Policies` directory. If this directory does not exist in your application, Laravel will create it for you:`php artisan make:policy CvPolicy`

The `make:policy` command will generate an empty policy class. If you would like to generate a class with the basic "CRUD" policy methods already included in the class, you may specify a **--model** when executing the command:

```
php artisan make:policy CvPolicy --model=Cv
```